# Functions.php - Cannot Modify Header Information SOLVED

Tags: functions

I had issues with my images and followed a tutorial on a popular site that recommended adding one line of code to it. I did and it didn't work well, my images stayed the same. So I deleted the line. The code in `functions.php` looks exactly as it did before but my backend is showing error codes after some actions. I can't change the featured image in my latest post for example and one error message is always displayed on top.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /homepages/15/d614793103/htdocs/clickandbuilds/WordPress/MyCMS3/wp-content/themes/simplemag-child/functions.php:18)
>   in
>   /homepages/15/d614793103/htdocs/clickandbuilds/WordPress/MyCMS3/wp-includes/option.php
>   on line 828
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /homepages/15/d614793103/htdocs/clickandbuilds/WordPress/MyCMS3/wp-content/themes/simplemag-child/functions.php:18)
>   in
>   /homepages/15/d614793103/htdocs/clickandbuilds/WordPress/MyCMS3/wp-includes/option.php
>   on line 829"

I didn't backup anything since I just tried something out real quick and then went back to normal. I had no idea this could happen! I purchased the template a while ago, do you think I have to reinstall it?

EDIT: This is my functions file and line 18 is empty! Do you think it matters how many spaces are in this document? I might have changed the spaces..

```
 <?php
/**
 * SimpleMag child theme functions & definitions
**/

/**
 * Parent theme style.css
**/

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

?>
```

EDIT NUMBER TWO: I SOLVED IT!!

Okay I figured it out :D Even though I had no backup, I just called my hosting service (1und1 - German) and they back up all your data for 6 days anyway. Amazing! I used Filezilla to upload the functions.php backup. Even if I didn't have 1und1, apparently you can extract the functions.php out of your theme files zip. This tutorial is great for Germans: seiten-wechsel.org/wordpress/… (I wrote this down in case someone stumbles across my thread)

Comment: And what does line 18 of your functions file, found here: `/homepages/15/d614793103/htdocs/clickandbuilds/WordPress/MyCMS3/wp-content/themes/simplemag-child/`, look like? Could you [edit your question ( using the edit button )](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/257856/edit) and add in that code in [a formatted way](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)?

Comment: Hey! thank you for answering, I added the whole functions file. It's not even 18 lines long! do you think it's important how many lines and spaces are in there? I might have removed an empty line, so the whole document is one line less long. I mean usually that doesn't matter for code?

Comment: you have a space before `<?php`, remove that space and delete the ending `?>`

Comment: But that was there before! Do you really think it's a good idea to delete something that was in there all along? I really don't want to do this

Comment: @MalinRouge, in this case, yes. I second Fayaz's advice. There still may be another issue, but what he's suggested is a best practice.

Comment: Suddenly I can't access my admin panel?  A few hours ago I could! How is it possible that it gets worse when I haven't even changed something?? There is a blank page and "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/15/d614793103/htdocs/clickandbuilds/WordPress/MyCMS3/wp-content/themes/simplemag-child/functions.php:18) in /homepages/15/d614793103/htdocs/clickandbuilds/WordPress/MyCMS3/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179"
What can I do now? I'm not even able to get to the functions file (at least my whole blog is still there and visible)

Comment: Okay I figured it out :D Even though I had no backup, I just called my hosting service (1und1 - German) and they back up all your data for 6 days anyway. Amazing! I used Filezilla to upload the functions.php backup. Even if I didn't have 1und1, apparently you can extract the functions.php out of your theme files zip. This tutorial is great for Germans: http://www.seiten-wechsel.org/wordpress/wordpress-wie-man-aenderungen-an-der-functions-php-richtig-macht/ (I wrote this down in case someone stumbles across my thread)